# Stopping/Starting windows hook in background thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, hook

I'm trying to install a windows hook, running in a background thread, until it's stopped by the user by calling `cancelRun()`.

however, when `installHook()` is called after a `cancelRun()`, I'm getting a "abort has been called" exception.

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

class GestureEngine{
private:
    static HHOOK hHook_;
    std::thread thread_;

    bool cancelRun_ = false;

public:
    GestureEngine(){
    }

    static GestureEngine& instance();

    static inline LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(const int nCode, const WPARAM wParam, const LPARAM lParam)
    {
        // ....
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook_, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    void threadproc();

    void installHook();

    void cancelRun();


};
```

Code:

```
#include "GestureEngine.h"

HHOOK GestureEngine::hHook_ = NULL;

GestureEngine& GestureEngine::instance(){
    static GestureEngine s_instance;
    return s_instance;
}

void GestureEngine::installHook(){
    thread_ = std::thread(&GestureEngine::threadproc, this);
    cancelRun_ = false;
}

void GestureEngine::cancelRun(){
    if (cancelRun_ == false) {
        cancelRun_ = true;

        thread_.join();
        thread_.detach();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook_);

        cancelRun_ = false;
    }   
}

void GestureEngine::threadproc(){
    MSG msg;
    hHook_= SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, NULL, NULL );

    while(!cancelRun_){
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    };
    return;
}
```

The error occurs when executing the line `thread_ = std::thread(&GestureEngine::threadproc, this);` in the `installHook()` method

Comment: Any more details about the problem?

Comment: `cancelRun_` should really be atomic and volatile. Better yet, make it an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) and call [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) in place of your **blocking** `GetMessage` call.

Answer (score 0):

I see the function 'threadproc' is member of Class GestureEngine, maybe you can try set it as global member or static funcion.